# How to auto_increment a field or index in my Parse class?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want something like

```
objectid   id   name   lastname   pic
 hx5w887   1   name1   lastname1  pic1
 lops4wus  2   name2   lastname2  pic2
 zh7w8sa   3   name3   lastname3   pic3
```

I don't want to change the objectId, just I want that field and every time I save an object increment in 1.  I am searched a lot in google, about this, it is no possible at least you can something with Cloud Parse code, but I do not know how to make this function, I don't know if "Increment" can help me with this, and I do not know  how to run the function anyway.

```
 Parse.Cloud.afterSave("counter", function(request) {

  var nameId = request.object.get("name").id;

  var Name = Parse.Object.extend("Name");
  var query = new Parse.Query(Name);
  query.get(nameId).then(function(post) {

    post.increment("idkey",+1);
    post.save();
  }, function(error) {
    throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
  });
});
```

I deploy and

call the function in Android

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("counter", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new FunctionCallback<String>() {
    //    @Override
    public void done(String result, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {

        } else {
            //    handleError();

        }
    }
});
```

But nothing happens, what can be the problem? Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ParseCloud 'beforeSave' functionality.
You can declare a code which will run before saving a new object of a specific class.
In this code you query for your class items, order it and get the first item (the highest value) then you can the next value (highest +1) to the new saved object.

For more info you can take a look at [Parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide) and in this [thread](https://www.parse.com/questions/can-i-have-something-similar-to-auto_increment-field-for-a-pfobject)  (it is not in java but it is very similar)

EDIT: Since Parse is not longer is now an open source might be that things have changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my life

Comment: Can you please add some examples, BTW the links do not work!

Comment: @EhsanErshadi - Parse project is no longer maintained by facebook so might be that things and links were changed. If this is a new project I highly recommend you to check also Firebase which I start using and is a very good alternative.